# min(f(x), 5) integrability

Tags: calculus, integration

Q: If $f(x)$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, let $g(x)=min(f(x),5)$. Is $g(x)$ integrable on $[a,b]$?

Does the number that g(x) chooses matter? (ie. can the 5 really just be any constant?)

My Start: I would think yes, just because any part where g(x) chooses f(x) is obviously integrable, and any constant is also integrable so is it just integrable everywhere?

Answer (score 1):

$\min(a, b)=\dfrac{a+b-|a-b|}{2}$. If $a$ is an integrable function and $b$ is a constant, then the right hand side should be Lebesgue integrable.